# something wrong with wandb.login() ？

Tags: wandb

Failed to detect the name of this notebook, you can set it manually with the WANDB_NOTEBOOK_NAME environment variable to enable code saving.
wandb: Currently logged in as: xxx (use `wandb login --relogin` to force relogin)

Comment: I've got the same issue.  Just showed up recently.